# Submit a form, then redirect to paypal button

Tags: php, post, paypal, http-headers

I need to submit a form to put username and password into my database, then i need to redirect the user to a paypal button I have created.

I can only think to redirect with the header() command but how can I POST variables to the new page?

Comment: Have the form submit to PayPal directly and in `onsubmit` for the form execute ajax to your own server to record username/password.

Comment: You dont have to worry about that they will be available using $name = $_POST['name']

Answer (score 2):

You can't redirect to PayPal with a POST, only a GET. However, you could do everything via AJAX in javascript (such as the jQuery $.post function) so that you first post to your PHP script and then in the result of that post to PayPal. Here is a rough "sketch" of how this would work:

```
var postData = {some_post_variable: "some value", another_post_variable: "some other value"};
$.post('yourserver.com/yourscript.php', postData, function (data) {
    // I'll assume the PHP script echoes "1" back for a successful post.
    if (data == 1) {
        //Now post to PayPal:
        var paypalData = {someData: "paypal data", etc...};
        $.post('your_paypal_url', paypalData, function(data) {
            // Now handle your PayPal post result here.
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. use username and password feilds in your form to post the data

Step 2. then insert the data to db

Step 3. check data is inserted if true then redirect to paypal button page using header("Location:") as below and on the paypal page collect user info from the query string using GET method

header("Location: yoururl.com?username=XXXXXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXXXXXXX")